# GraphQL Stack Overflow API endpoint W.I.P

Tags: app, library, golang

#### About:

Currently a [GraphQL endpoint is available here](https://stack-exchange-graphql-server.azurewebsites.net/), meant to facilitate apps wanting to query data from StackExchange but with the GraphQL spec. High speed, built with go and hosted on Azure. Source code is [here](https://github.com/snimmagadda1/stack-exchange-graphql-server) and welcoming contributions! Here's an example of a relay-based cursor query!

```
query usersPagination {
  allUsersCursor(first: 50, after: "MjAyNzU=", where: {order: {field: reputation, order: DESC}}) {
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
    }
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        displayName
        reputation
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can do cool stuff with GraphQL, like build an entire Q&A page on Stack Overflow with a single query.

As this thing gets built out, I think there's a ton of potential for consumers. For example, with minimal code you could add the ability to search for unanswered questions & build something around that...

Right now it is in P.O.C mode and only serving data from `anime.stackexchange.com` while the GraphQL schema gets implemented fully.

#### Screenshot / Code Snippet:

[image]

Heres a pic of the GraphQL playground.

#### Download / Install:

This can be run as a docker image or from source. Running instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/snimmagadda1/stack-exchange-graphql-server).

#### Contact:

Sai Nimmagadda

Twitter: @[Funsaized](https://twitter.com/FunSaized)

Web: [s11a.com](https://s11a.com)

#### License: MIT

What license is your app/library/wrapper/script released under, if any?
Or if it is paid, how much does it cost and how do we buy it?

#### Code:

Written with Go, deployed on Azure. [Source code and contributions welcome here](https://github.com/snimmagadda1/stack-exchange-graphql-server)!

Comment: Just imported health.stackexchange.com data into the DB and it serves that flawlessly! pretty cool if you ask me ... @StackOverflow why don't y'all build this with me ;)